# How to use the xdg-mime command

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, mime, file-type

Can someone provide example on how to use (with GNOME Ubuntu) the [XDG-MIME](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=xdg-mime) command? I'm struggling to get anything working even with the docs.

For example if I want to register the extension .mfe with an application called MyApp what would the steps be? This is my attempt so far, I would appreciate any pointers on getting this right...

This is my xml (MyApp-MyFileType.xml) **How is the file name relavent?**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<mime-info xmlns='http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info'>
  <mime-type type="text/mfe">
    <comment>File for MyApp</comment>
    <glob pattern="*.mfe"/>
  </mime-type>
</mime-info>
```

**Then is run this command?**

```
xdg-mime install MyApp-MyFileType.xml
```

And then I run this? **What does the xxx relate to?, I understand it to be an identifier to my application but how do I define it?**

```
xdg-mime default xxx.desktop text/mfe
```

Answer (score 26):

All the needed information is in `man xdg-mime`.

1. Check the actual mime-type with `xdg-mime query filetype filename.ext` (the response could be e.g. `application/octet-stream`)
2. If you decide to create your own mime-type you should edit an XML file like the example you gave. You should check if the mime-type name you want to create exists to not override it. You can see the registered mime-types in `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list`.
3. Then, as you pointed out, it's time to register the new mime-type with `sudo xdg-mime install --mode system MyApp-MyFileType.xml` to install for all users on the system.
4. At this point, if you check again the mime-type (like in step 1.) you should have the desired response (your new mime-type).
5. Now it's time to register the new mime-type with the desired application. The association is done with `sudo xdg-mime default MyApp.desktop text/mfe` (in your example). To see the available `.desktop` files just do: `ls /usr/share/applications | less` (I think this is what you were looking for).
6. The last step is registering the icon with `xdg-icon-resource` but that's another topic.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I would use `find /usr/share/applications -iname '*xxx*.desktop'` as it recurses into subdirectory, specific for `xxx`, and it is case-insensitive. BTW, KDE has a GUI for this.

Comment: @Polv I have nothing with find (GNU findutils) 4.7.0 and Ubuntu 20.04 LTS...

Answer (score 7):

To be able to `xdg-open afile.myapp`:

1. make a description xml for the file type, like you did.
2. run `xdg-mime install vendor-filetype.xml`
3. make a `myapp.desktop` file for your application, like this: [.desktop example](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/apa.html)
4. run `xdg-mime default myapp.desktop filetype`

Answer (score 0):

Adding a **applied case**, for composed filenames, since `xdg-mime default` was not working for me in this particular case.

---

The goal: associate all files `*.mybot.json` with a special dedicated script `mybot`, while retaining the default behavior of a regular `.json` file (Eq: dropping in Firefox will still recognize the files as `.json`, but clicking them will open the pre defined `mybot` script)

---

✅ Create `mybot.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<mime-info xmlns='http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info'>
  <mime-type type="application/mybot">
    <comment>My Bot json data</comment>
    <glob pattern="*.mybot.json"/>
  </mime-type>
</mime-info>
```

---

✅ Create `mybot.desktop`, and test it:

Clicking it should launch the script called `mybot` in `/home/bots/`.

ⓘ The target script `mybot` must be set executable and be a *hashbang* shell script, with the lang interpreter set on the first line, because launched by bash.

ⓘ We can use one of the numerous icon existing in `/usr/share/icons`.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=mybot
Exec=bash -c '/home/bots/mybot;/bin/bash'
Icon=utilities-terminal
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Categories=Development;
```

⚠️ It is important to click it one time and mark it as trusted. The icon will change after that.

---

✅ Mime install on the machine, files explorer will then start to recognize `*.mybot.json` files as `My Bot json data (application/mybot)`.

```
sudo xdg-mime install mybot.xml
```

---

✅ Then, simply copy the .desktop launcher in `/usr/share/applications`:

```
sudo cp mybot.desktop /usr/share/applications
```

---

Now as example, a file `*.mybot.json` downloaded from your website or coming by email can be quickly opened with a given script on the local machine directly from the browser. It allows to create a wild ecosystem of automations!